# Is there a clientside only way to handle emit complete in socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io

In my case I have to sync repositories via socket using socket.io.
On my local machine it's working well (high bandwith no latency...). But I tought about emiting bigger objects to server and then some locking is required on client during sending these objects.

So the first known possible way is to emmit a "gotData and" listen on client.
But is there an way to detect completion only from client side?

e.g. Like the DUMMY example:

```
//Some dummy code
socket.emit('syncObject', oObj).complete(function(evt){
    console.log('finished emit');
});
```

Comment: Are you looking to make sure the emit completed or make sure the server has processed the emit?

Comment: Right I just want to make sure the emmit has completed not the following process on server

Answer (score 0):

This is a little bit of a hack but you can include a callback with your emit and immediately call it on the server side when it receives the message.

client

```
socket.emit('syncObject', oObj, function() {
  console.log('got message');
});
```

server

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(80);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.on('syncObject', function (obj, cb) {
    cb();
    // handle obj data
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Didn't found your solution in socket.io documentation. Try it out later at home